# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'date' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, swing

My application is getting this error:

> Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2-24-2015' for column 'POrder_Date' at row 1

I have MySQL connector java v-5.1.7

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
String date1, mon, datex, year, yearx, currentDate;
int d, d1;
```

following code is in my class,s constructor:

```
date1=df.format(date);
    d=date1.indexOf('/');
    mon=date1.substring(0,d);
    d1=date1.lastIndexOf('/');
    datex=date1.substring(d+1,d1);
    yearx=date1.substring(d1+1);
    year="20"+yearx;
    currentDate=mon+"-"+datex+"-"+year;
    System.out.println("current date  "+currentDate);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that we are volunteers here, and that it's time - consuming to try to understand hundreds of lines of code. Can you please edit your question to include just the offending lines?

Comment: The canonical text representation in MySQL happens to be `2015-02-24`, not  `2-24-2015`.

Comment: i tried that but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

mysql default date format "yyyy-mm-dd".change date format then store .may be it will work.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
String  date1,mon,datex,year,yearx,currentDate;
int d,d1;
date1=df.format(date);
d=date1.indexOf('/');
mon=date1.substring(0,d);
d1=date1.lastIndexOf('/');
datex=date1.substring(d+1,d1);
yearx=date1.substring(d1+1);
year="20"+yearx;
currentDate=mon+"-"+datex+"-"+year;
System.out.println("current date  "+currentDate);
//change currentdate format MM-dd-yyyy into yyyy-MM-dd
try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse(currentDate);
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-  dd").format(convertedCurrentDate));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

check print date format like(2015-05-25).

Comment: hey,peter it didn't worked...btw thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here:

Either use [`updateDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#updateDate(java.lang.String,%20java.sql.Date)) where you presently use `rs.updateString(2,podate)`.  Pass a `Date` object to `updateDate()`.

Or change your internal date formatting throughout to comply with the ISO `yyyy-mm-dd` standard.